# Python's self vs instance

Tags: python, django

What is the difference between the self and instance keywords in Python 3?

I see code like,

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    """
    Update and return an existing `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
    """
    instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
    instance.code = validated_data.get('code', instance.code)
    instance.linenos = validated_data.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
    instance.language = validated_data.get('language', instance.language)
    instance.style = validated_data.get('style', instance.style)
    instance.save()
    return instance
```

Comment: Neither is a keyword. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

Comment: This looks to be Django. Follow the Django documentation. Add a Django tag next time you use stackoverflow.  Don't assume that Django always follows the everyday way of doing things in Python, because it doesn't.  In particular, it uses a "declarative" pattern for  constructing complex classes. It works as per its documentation. There is some pretty deep "magic" behind the scenes that most programmers have absolutely no need to know about.

Comment: noted, I added Django Tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither `self` nor `instance` are keywords in Python. The identifier `self` is used by convention as the first parameter of instance methods in a class. The object instance on which a method is called is automatically passed in as the first parameter.

In the above snippet, `update` is most probably a method of some class and `self` seems to be the conventional first parameter as described above. The second parameter `instance` is just another parameter and the name `instance` does not have any significance in Python.

Answer (score 2):

The snippet is a bit short but `instance` is not a keyword (neither `self`, that is just convention).

It is an argument to another instance of another (maybe same) class.

Answer (score 2):

The question is rather generic, but let me see if I can shed some light on it for you:

`self` refers to the class(by convention, not a keyword) of which `update` is a part. The class has variables and methods and you can refer to these with the `self` keyword(not a reserved keyword) by calling `self.update(instance, validated_data)`

In the case of the snippet above, `self` refers to the class. `instance` likely refers to some `model` instance "the big hint is the `instance.save()` and `validated_data` is a dictionary or class object with attributes you are `get`tting and assigning to `instance` attributes before saving them

Hope this helps

Comment: The value Python automatically assigns to the first argument in a method (in this case the argument is named 'self', which is Python convention) does *not* refer to a class.  It contains a reference to a particular *instance* of a class.

Comment: `self` does **not** refer to the class. `self` refers to the current instance of the class.

Comment: which is why it "refers to" and not "is" the class - but het semantics is wonderfully subjective

Answer (score 0):

You are refering to the implementation of a Serializer class in Django REST framework, that serializes data into Json with help of a Model object.
This class has a method called 'update', which takes the Snippet  Model object 'instance' as an input, and then updates this object with the validated_data. Like it was mentioned before 'instance' is not a reserved keyword in Python.

A serializer class is very similar to a Django Form class, and includes similar validation flags on the various fields, such as required, max_length and default.

In order get clearer idea I am sharing the complete class implementation.

```
class SnippetSerializer(serializers.Serializer):

    id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
    title = serializers.CharField(required=False, allow_blank=True, max_length=100)
    code = serializers.CharField(style={'base_template': 'textarea.html'})
    linenos = serializers.BooleanField(required=False)
    language = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=LANGUAGE_CHOICES, default='python')
    style = serializers.ChoiceField(choices=STYLE_CHOICES, default='friendly')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        """
        Create and return a new `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        return Snippet.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        """
        Update and return an existing `Snippet` instance, given the validated data.
        """
        instance.title = validated_data.get('title', instance.title)
        instance.code = validated_data.get('code', instance.code)
        instance.linenos = validated_data.get('linenos', instance.linenos)
        instance.language = validated_data.get('language', instance.language)
        instance.style = validated_data.get('style', instance.style)
        instance.save()
        return instance
```